# Lando adminer ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT on login submit

Tags: docker, adminer, lando

I am using Lando to create an environment that includes Adminer as a service. When I go into Adminer and try to login, I get the following page after pressing the 'Login' button:

> This page isn’t working
>
> adminer.myproject.lndo.site sent an invalid response.
>
> ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Below is my .lando.yml file:

```
name: myproject
recipe: drupal7
config:
  php: '5.6'
  via: apache
  webroot: web
  database: mariadb
  drush: ^8
  xdebug: true

proxy:
  mailhog:
    - mail.myproject.lndo.site
  pma:
    - pma.myproject.lndo.site
  adminer:
    - adminer.myproject.lndo.site

services:
  mailhog:
    type: mailhog
    hogfrom:
      - appserver
    portforward: 1026
  pma:
    type: phpmyadmin
    hosts:
      - database
  adminer:
    type: compose
    services:
      image: dehy/adminer
      command: /bin/s6-svscan /etc/services.d
    portforward: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred after installing Lando v3.0.0-rrc.3. I've filed an issue at Lando project here: https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/2149